# Failing to replace a url with sed in shell

Tags: sed

I'm having a bit of an issue with a shell script, replacing url in a json file with sed, with an url stored on a variable. The code is this:

```
sed -i "30s+.*+\"uri\":\"$MONGO_URI\",+" temp.json
```

To replace the MONGO_URI in the json:

```
    {
    ...
    "requestsDB": {
      "uri": "MONGO_URI",
      "password":"MONGO_PW",
      "database": "temp-db"},
    "mlAPI": {
      "server": "..."}
    ...
    }

#into

    {
    ...
    "requestsDB": {
      "uri": "mongodb://admin:password@*****725/compose?authSource=admin?ssl=true?retryWrites=false",
      "password":"MONGO_PW",
      "database": "temp-db"},
    "mlAPI": {
      "server": "...}
    ...
    }
```

But instead I'm getting this:

```
"uri" :"mongodb://admin:password@*****725/compose?authSource=admin      "uri": "MONGO_URI",ssl=true      "uri": "MONGO_URI",retryWrites=false",
```

Don't really know what's causing the issue, don't know if anybody can help?

Comment: If this is a json file you are trying to edit, then IMHO experts do advice always to use tools which understand json like `jq`.

Comment: I've tried with jq but was only able to create a new uri instead of replacing the actually value I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68020192/failing-to-replace-a-url-with-sed-in-shell#comment120223576_68020192), using [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) <sup>[docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)</sup> would be a much better solution to alter JSON

---

An example using JQ where the `temp.json` looks like this

```json
{
    "requestsDB":
    {
        "uri": "MONGO_URI",
        "password": "MONGO_PW",
        "database": "temp-db"
    },
    "mlAPI":
    {
        "server": "..."
    }
}
```

We can use the following bash calls to alter the `uri`:

```sh
# Hardcoded URL
jq --arg MOGO_URI "Example URL" '.requestsDB.uri |= $MOGO_URI' temp.json

# If your new url is available through a bash var, you can use:
MOGO_URI='Example URL'
jq --arg MOGO_URI "$MOGO_URI" '.requestsDB.uri |= $MOGO_URI' temp.json
```

This will produce:

```json
{
  "requestsDB": {
    "uri": "Example URL",
    "password": "MONGO_PW",
    "database": "temp-db"
  },
  "mlAPI": {
    "server": "..."
  }
}
```

[JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/c8VnKyj45a)

Comment: If I run this `jq --arg MONGO_URI $MONGO_URI '.requestsDB.uri |= $MONGO_URI' temp.json`, the outcome I get is  `"requestsDB": {"uri": "MONGO_URI"},requestsDB": {"uri": "mongodb://admi****},` instead of replacing it.

Comment: It seems to duplicate the value of `requestsDB.uri` instead of replacing it

Comment: Please share the JSON you're dealing with so I can provide a better example!

Comment: `"requestsDB": {"uri": "MONGO_URI","password":"MONGO_PW","database": "temp-db"},"mlAPI": {}`, this is just a small portion, the whole json has 50 lines, hope it's helps. Thnks

Comment: This isn't valid JSON? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68020192/edit) your question to add it there so the format is a bit nicer

Comment: Just added the json to the question above.

Comment: I just copied the code as it is but instead of replacing the value, is creating an aditional `"requestsDB": {"uri": "mongodb://admi****"`, and still keeping the `"requestsDB": {"uri": "MONGO_URI"` in the json

Comment: Then the path is deeper, or your' not sharing the complete json. As you can see in the online demo, this works fine.

Comment: Ok seems it was the path that was deeper. Thnks.